# PHP get yesterdays date unless weekend

Tags: php, date

I need to get yesterday's date to show the market close date. This only applies to Monday through Friday as the markets are not open on the weekend. Using this format how would I do that?

```
<?php
$yesterday = date("Y-m-d", mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m") , date("d")-1,date("Y")));
echo $yesterday;
?>
```

Comment: `date("w")` will give you the numeric day of the week (0 through 6). From there you can write a conditional for just weekdays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check what day the current week day is with `date('w')`.
Note that Sunday is 0, and Saturday is 6.

And with that information, you can do:

```
$yesterday = strtotime(date('w') == 0 || date('w') == 6 ? 'last friday' : 'yesterday');
echo date('Y-m-d', $yesterday);
```

Basically, if it's a weekend, you ask for the last friday, otherwise, you ask PHP for yesterday.

If you don't like it in one line:

```
$w = date('w');
if($w == 0 || $w == 6)
    $yesterday = strtotime('last friday');
else
    $yesterday = strtotime('yesterday');

$yesterday = date('Y-m-d', $yesterday);
```

In our case today, `Tuesday, June 14th 2016`, it will return `2016-06-13`.

For more information about the date function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: Thanks, I do like the one line option. Very informative.

Comment: No problem @WillLong. Would you mind marking this as the answer please? :)

Comment: Yes marked. Again thank you Chin.  After going over it with my client, i also need to look to last friday if it's a Monday as well, so I adjust the line as such...

     $yesterday = strtotime(date('w') == 0 || strtotime(date('w') == 1 || date('w') == 6 ? 'last friday' : 'yesterday');
echo date('Y-m-d', $yesterday);

is that right?

Comment: Yes that's correct @WillLong. Since you have 3 weekdays, you could use this as an alternative: `$yesterday = in_array(date('w'), array(0, 1, 6)) ? 'last friday' : 'yesterday'); echo date('Y-m-d', $yesterday);`

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to do it:

```
$date= new \DateTime();
$oneDay = new \DateInterval('P1D');
$date->sub($oneDay);
if ('Sunday' === $date->format('l')) {
    $date->sub($oneDay);
}
if ('Saturday' === $date->format('l')) {
    $date->sub($oneDay);
}
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

I just get today's date, subtract one day, and check to see if it is a Sunday. If so, subtract a day. Then I do the same thing for a Saturday. Ultimately you end up with the last weekday.

Keep in mind this is different then business day's as that Friday may be a holiday and the markets may be closed.